# Will Windows 7 Remote Desktop client connect to 12.04 server?

Tags: 12.04, windows-7, rdp

What, if any, versions of Windows RDP will connect to Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS 64bit ?

Comment: Please remember to accept/upvote the best answer to your question (tick/check mark on the left). This way, the question is marked as "answered" and future readers can refer to it knowing the solution works. Thank you...:)

Answer (score 3):

All versions of Windows Remote Desktop, from Windows XP to Windows 7, will connect **as long as you're running the `xrdp` server on the Ubuntu server.**

Install it with

```
sudo apt-get install xrdp
```